# Asp.net - What do to after serving a file via Response.OutputStream

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am serving an docx file through my web application. This is done in response to a DropDownList index being changed, I have AutoPostBack set to true. I have a number of options that can be selected via checkboxes and when the dropdown is changed the file that is created is based on the checked options.

So what I am doing is when the event fires I do some magic to create a document then serve it:

```
Protected Sub myDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged

' a bunch of things happen here but the end result is the contents of a docx file in a MemoryStream with the
' name mainStream

'here is where I set up the response and serve the file:

Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=document.docx")
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
mainStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
mainStream.Close()
mainStream.Dispose()
Response.End()
```

Now my question is, what should I do at this point? It seems I have to call Response.End() send the buffered content but that leaves me sitting on a page with checkboxes checked and my dropdown on the changed option. If I hit any other buttons on the page that cause a postback it seems that the selected index changed event of my dropdown fires again.

What I would like to do is redirect after sending the file. Response.redirect will not work as Response.End() stops page execution. Could anyone tell me how situations like this are typically handled? Could anyone tell me why the selected index event for my dropdown fires again if another control on the page does a postback after the file has been served? Any advice is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676734/redirecting-to-another-page-after-response-end-has-been-called-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but the answer in that thread did not work for me. Setting the refresh didn't seem to do anything. I still get served the file but it doesn't change after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to approach this depending on the complexity of your application and the desired behavior in the page after the selection.

The way that we handle this situation is to gather all of the details for generating the file in javascript and pass them in a query string to an ashx page that we open in a new window from javascript. The ashx page will then generate the file and stream the response back to the user.

We take this approach because the request for the file doesn't change anything about the user's interaction with the page.

The other approach is to generate the file during the postback and save it in a temporary location. You could then move the user to a different page or update the current page and then execute some javascript that will fetch the file for the user. If the file is generated in an exposed folder, you could just open the file directly or if not, you could use the ashx trick above. In either case, your code behind will have to include, in a hidden field or javascript, a reference to the generated file so that the client side knows how to find it.